# Using a trigger to change the date format

Tags: mysql, time, triggers

I have a DB with times. The format is this: `30/09/2014 9:00:00`.

The field is in string format and I don't want change it if it's possible.

I need to change the mask when I do the inserts because I need this format: `30/09/2014 09:00:00`.

The command to change a mask in a string is this:

```
UPDATE fichajes set tiempo=STR_TO_DATE("30/09/2014 9:00:00", '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i');
```

I suppose I need a trigger to change the mask, but I don't know how to use it. I do something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER fichajes AFTER INSERT ON fichajes
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE fecha VARCHAR(50);
SET fecha =(SELECT fecha from fichajes);
UPDATE fichajes set fecha=STR_TO_DATE(@fecha, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i');
END;
```

This does not work and I don't know of how to work with triggers. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the relationship between prueba and fichajes? Do you have priveleges to alter table fichajes? Why don't you want to change datatype for field?

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake with this:
UPDATE fichajes set fecha=STR_TO_DATE(@fecha, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i');
(I commit a error, it's not prueba, it's fichajes.)
I have priveleges, yes.

I don't want to change datatype because I need use the date like string for work in a function.

Comment: You know that STR_TO_DATE has a counterpart DATE_FORMAT?

Comment: I think that STR_TO_DATE can put a mask in a varchar field without that the field be type date. 
I mean, takes a string and a format string, and returns a DATETIME value, and when you update, 
this value be insert perfectly in its varchar datatype column. 
I tried this: UPDATE fichajes set fecha=STR_TO_DATE("30/09/2014 9:00:00", '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i');
and it works.